# How can i get the tree style directory in linux centos to text file

Tags: linux, shell, centos, directory-structure

I have the directories and then subdirectories inside it.

How can i export the `directory tree` with `custom depth level` and then export that to a text file

basically i am looking for shell function

`printTree(level)`

so i get one text file like this

```
Dir1
-------file1
-------file2
-------dir1
-------dir2

Dir12
----------file1
```

How can i do that

Comment: Have you tried the `tree` command? It's probably not installed by default, but should be easy to get with `yum install tree`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sudo yum install tree`

`tree Dir1` and you will get a result such as

```
Dir1
├── Dir11
│   ├── Dir111
│   └── Dir112
├── Dir12
└── Dir13
    └── Dir131

6 directories, 0 files
```

then you can use `tree Dir1 > mytreefile.txt` to export that to a text file named `mytreefile.txt`

Comment: Can i specify depth , so that i don't go beyound certain depth of inside subdirs

Comment: use `-L` to control thee max display depth of the directory tree.